# what is a relationship between a string representation of date and datetime object on this plt's plot?

Tags: python, string, datetime, matplotlib

I am working on Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney.
I encountered this code below. `spx` is a series consisting of datetime type data.

```
from datetime import datetime 
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

data = pd.read_csv('examples/spx.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
spx = data['SPX']
spx.plot(ax=ax,style='k-')

crisis_data = [
    (datetime(2007,10,11),'Peek of bull market'),
    (datetime(2008,3,12),"Bear Stearns Fails"),
    (datetime(2008,9,15),"Lehman Bankruptcy")
]

for date, label in crisis_data:
    ax.annotate(label,xy=(date,spx.asof(date)+75),xytext=(date,spx.asof(date)+225),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black',headwidth=4,width=2,headlength=4), horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='top')
    
ax.set_xlim(['1/1/2007','1/1/2011'])
ax.set_ylim([600,1800])

ax.set_title('Important dates in the 2008-2009 financial crisis')
```

As experiements, I changed datetime objects in `crisis_data` into string like `"2007-10-11"`. I expected that I had a kind of error. But, the plot is successfully created with correct annotations. I would like to know why this is possible.